# Jenkins windows slave batch job says success but job did not run

Tags: perl, jenkins

Trying to set up a jenkins v2.46.3 slave on windows 2016 server to run a batch file.

It looks like it is working but the batch file does not actually run. The script does not generate the expected log file and nothing shows up in task manager on the slave

The console output of the job looks like this:

```
Started by user xxx
Building remotely on xxx-Windows (windows) in workspace c:\Jenkins\workspace\xxx
[xxx] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson4948156451026881586.bat
c:\Jenkins\workspace\xxx>C:\QA\xxx\Perl\Tests\runxxxTests.bat
c:\Jenkins\workspace\xxx>cd C:\QA\xxx\Perl\Tests 
C:\QA\xxx\Perl\Tests>runxxxTests.pl -f test_suite_test.list 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

If I run the batch file manually it works as expected.

There do not seem to be any errors. How can I troubleshoot this further ?

Comment: What kind of job is it? Are you using a jenkinsfile? Can we see your pipeline script?

Comment: Job type is "Execute Windows batch command" with one line: "C:\QA\xxx\Perl\Tests\runxxxTests.bat" the contents of that file is "cd C:\QA\xxx\Perl\Tests; runxxxTests.pl -f test_suite_test.list" if I run it using WMI "WMIC /node:xxx process call create "cmd.exe /c C:\QA\xxx\Perl\Tests\runxxxTests.bat" that works.

Comment: Where is the log file being saved?

Is it possible its being saved to the workspace when calling it from jenkins?

Comment: The log file would be created in the "C:\QA\xxx\Perl\Tests" directory. The script also sends me an email when complete and that isn't happening either when the jenkins job runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to this was changing the log on rights of the Jenkins and Jenkins Agent services on the windows slave from LocalSystem to a privileged account.